# React Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on [event.target.name]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a 3rd-party component using Phone Input here https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2#react-phone-input-2 I need to get the value input by the user and set the form state using the method below that handles onChange:

```
const handlePhoneChange = (event) => {
  setFormState({
    ...formState,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
};
```

This is my configuration for the 3rd-party component below:

```
<PhoneInput
      country={"us"}
      error={hasError("phone")}
      helperText={hasError("phone") ? formState.errors.phone[0] : null}
      name="phone"
      value={formState.values.phone || ""}
      onChange={handlePhoneChange}
    />
```

However, I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined** when I try to type a number in the phoneInput component. Kindly help me resolve this.

Comment: What does `console.log(event.target)` display when you place it before `setFormState`?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Thanks. I got an answer for this question. However, I need to access the formState,s value now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [read the documentation for the `onchange` event](https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2#events), there are 4 arguments that are accessible: `onChange(value, country, e, formattedValue)`.

The way you're accessing `event` is incorrect, because you're accessing the first positional arugment, which is the `value` of the input. You get an error trying to access `event.target` since it is not an `Event` object.

The `Event` object is available as the third positional argument, so if you use it as such, it should work:

```
const handlePhoneChange = (value, country, event) => {
  setFormState({
    ...formState,
    [event.target.name]: value,
  });
};
```

Comment: This is correct @Terry In that case after I set it, if I need to get the value set to the formState, how can access it if I am using this method const testData = (evt) => {
    console.log("phone: " + formState.phone);
  }; but I get the error "undefined"

Comment: Also, I realized that the event.target.name returns nothing if you run console.log to see what it returns. that means the the value is not being set in State

Comment: I had to use inputProps={{
    name: 'phone',
    required: true,
    autoFocus: true
  }}